# Create a sprite and give it a custom class

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit, sprite

I have a custom class named `Ball` and a sprite in `GameScene.sks`:

**GameScene.sks:**

```
var ball:Ball!
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    ball.setUp()
    addChild(ball)

}
```

**Ball.swift:**

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
class Ball: SKSpriteNode {
     func setUp() {
         self.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ball")
    }
}
```

But it throws this error:`Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`
Can someone help ? Thanks

Comment: Which line throws that error? Is it `ball.setUp`? How are you assigning a value to `ball` in `GameScene.sks`?

Comment: It throws the error on this line: "bal.setUp()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you never actually assign a value to `ball`, which is an implicitly unwrapped optional, so when you are trying to access it using `ball.setUp()`, its default `nil` value is force unwrapped.

Instead of directly modifying the `texture` property of your `SKSpriteNode` subclass, you should simply call its designated initializer, `Ball(imageNamed: "ball")` to instantiate the node.

So modify `GameScene.sks` accordingly:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    ball = Ball(imageNamed: "ball")
    addChild(ball)
}
```